# Google API Refresh Token

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I have been trying for the last few hours to print my refresh_token from the initial Google API call (even after de-authorizing and re-authorizing as others have suggested doing) but I still am not having any luck...the API works as expected but I want to set up refreshing functionality so my user does not lose access after token expires (resulting in errors).

Currently, the below code sets $_SESSION['refresh_token'] to null.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been banging my head against the keyboard for quite some time...

```
private function googleAnalyticsClient(){
    App::import('Vendor', 'google-api-php-client', array('file' => 'autoload.php'));
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfigFile(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json'); 
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
    $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly');

    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
        return $analytics;
    } else {
      $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/dashboard/oauthcallbacks';
      header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }
}

public function getOauth()
{
    App::import('Vendor', 'google-api-php-client', array('file' => 'autoload.php'));

    // Create the client object and set the authorization configuration
    // from the client_secrets.json you downloaded from the Developers Console.
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfigFile(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/dashboard/oauthcallbacks');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

    // Handle authorization flow from the server.
    if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
      $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
      header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    } else {
      $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
      $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
      $_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $client->getRefreshToken();
      $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/dashboard/tpstats';
      header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In getOauth() function add the following

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/dashboard/oauthcallbacks');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);    
$client->setAccessType('offline'); //To fetch refresh token(Refresh token issued only first time)
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force'); //Adding this will force for refresh token
```

Comment: By trial and error, I was finally able to get it to work. I just var_dump'd $client after $client->authenticate()...sometimes you just need some sleep :P thanks for the help