# Google authorization code flow - no refresh token

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I'm using Google API to obtain access and refresh tokens for offline access, however, the refresh token is always null.

The authorizationCode comes from the client, so I exchange it with the tokens on the server:

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
    HTTP_TRANSPORT,
    JSON_FACTORY,
    clientId,
    clientSecret,
    scopes)
.setAccessType("offline")
.build();

GoogleTokenResponse response = flow
    .newTokenRequest(authorizationCode)
    .setRedirectUri(redirectUri)
    .execute();
// response has access_token and id_token. don't see any refresh token here
return flow.createAndStoreCredential(response, null);
// this returns Credential with refreshToken = null
```

Client code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: '<my client id>',
        // Scopes to request in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
        scope: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appfolder'
        });
    });
    $('#signinButton').click(function() {
        auth2.grantOfflineAccess({'redirect_uri': 'postmessage'}).then(onSignIn);
    });
});
// the onSignIn function sends the one time code (i.e. authResult['code']) to the server
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

I saw this question: [Google OAuth: can't get refresh token with authorization code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31545712/google-oauth-cant-get-refresh-token-with-authorization-code) but it didn't really answer my question and I'm not aware of refresh token only being created the first time a user logs in.

**Edit:**

I believe this is actually a client side problem, because the consent window doesn't ask for offline access. Will update this question based on the results of a new question here: [Google javascript sign-in api: no offline access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949727/google-javascript-sign-in-api-no-offline-access)