# Google javascript sign-in api: no offline access

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

I'm trying to implement Google Sign-In for server-side apps as shown in Google documentation: [Google Sign-In for server-side apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow), but the consent window never asks for offline access. After selecting a user it just closes and calls the sign in handler function.

As a result, when I get the one time code and send it to the server, I cannot exchange it for a **refresh** token, only for access and id tokens.

Here is my client code:

**In the HTML file:**

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=init" async defer></script>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
var auth2;
function init() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: '<my client id>.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            scope: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appfolder'
        });
    });
    $('#signinButton').click(function() {
        auth2.grantOfflineAccess({'redirect_uri': 'postmessage'}).then(onSignIn);
    });
}

function onSignIn(authResult) {
    if (authResult['code']) {
    // Send the code to the server
    }
}
```

The project in Google console contains a web client credential with the relevant javascript origins and no Authorized redirect URIs.

What should I do to **force the consent window to ask for offline access**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm able to force the prompt for offline, by adding the param `'approval_prompt' : 'force'` to `auth2.grantOfflineAccess` function call.

E.g.

`auth2.grantOfflineAccess({'redirect_uri' : 'postmessage', 'approval_prompt' : 'force'}).then(onSignIn);`

Comment: Thank you Mael! It indeed asks for offline access each time and I have the refresh token.

Comment: Glad to see it works @burgi! Btw, are you able to grant incremental auth with the server side login? I'm stuck in this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35023983/incremental-combined-authorization-with-google-signin-for-server-side-apps and every new scope I ask user to authorize, the result token overrides the previous authorized scopes...

Comment: Sorry @Mael, I'm not using incremental auth. My business logic requires getting all the permissions in advanced.

Comment: Thank you so much - how were you able to find the approval_prompt? I couldn't find it in any of the documentation.

Comment: Just checking, it looks like i kinda duplicated this in my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349749/google-mybusiness-access-from-webservers-without-redirects I will try the answer and see if it works for me. So do you get a refresh token too?

Comment: approval_prompt=force no longer works see: https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client/issues/453