# Incremental combined authorization with Google SignIn for Server-Side Apps

Tags: google-signin, google-oauth, google-api-js-client, google-identity

When login with [Server-Side flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow), or ask authorization for additional scopes, with `auth2.grantOfflineAccess`, the result access/refresh token is not getting combined with previous authorized scopes, overriding the previous ones.

Even passing the param to js calls, e.g. `auth2.grantOfflineAccess({'include_granted_scopes' : 'true', ...})`, the param **`include_granted_scopes=true`** is NOT added to the generated URL.

When I manually append the param `&include_granted_scopes=true` to the generated url on popup window, the incremental combined authorization works, as [described in the protocol](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#incrementalAuth).

Are there any way to make incremental combined authorization with Google SignIn for Server-Side Apps?

Cheers

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the client library you might want to post it on the issue forum. https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client

Comment: I just submitted an Issue: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/214 . The workround I've found was to get all previous authorized scopes, by callink TokenInfo endpoint, concatenate the new scopes, and ask for authorization with the result string.

Comment: I believe this is working as intended. The way that incremental auth works from the JavaScript client library is that you provide the list of all the scopes that you want to receive a token for and then a token is minted for those scopes. The special thing that happens is that the user only is required to consent for the additional scopes they have not authorized for your app.

Comment: @class That works smoothly. The problem is that, when asking for offline access for additional scopes, the access/refresh tokens does NOT combine with previous authorized scopes. For that, the generated URL must include the param `include_granted_scopes=true` , as described in the underlining protocol here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#incrementalAuth

Comment: I'll see if I can reproduce the behavior for include_granted_scopes.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I am not seeing the behavior you're describing, demo here: https://gusclass.com/demos/button2/upgrade.html

Comment: Cool!! Take a look at the generated url of the popup... there is the param `access_type=offline`, but the `include_granted_scopes=true` is missing... this will cause the access/refresh tokens you receive to override the previous offline authorized tokens. Try for example, authorize for drive, than create another button with offline authorization for contacts... if you query tokenInfo endpoint, with the second access_token, you will get only access to contacts, not for drive...

Comment: Did you manage to do the incremental authorization, @Mael? I think I've the same problem because I want to request just the new scope, but I'm afraid that I need to ask for all the previous scopes aswell to generate the refresh token. Do you know if it's necessary to request all the scopes or it's possible to request the new ones and I'm not doing it properly? Btw, I've created a question where you can find more details about my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495056/google-oauth-2-0-incremental-authorization-with-offline-access