# How is the access_type=online oauth mode (no refresh token) supposed to work?

Tags: google-oauth

This question is has a lot in common to the previous question [Google OAuth: can't get refresh token with authorization code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31545712/google-oauth-cant-get-refresh-token-with-authorization-code) (and I won't be offended if it's considered a duplicate) but there are some differences: that question uses the Javascript and PHP libraries, and I'm using neither of those. That question wants to know how to get a refresh token, and I want to know if I *should* want a refresh token, or how the mode with no refresh tokens is intended to work.

I'm following this guide:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

The goal is to allow users to upload files from Google Drive to my web application.

I'm not using one of Google's favored programming languages, so I don't have a library abstracting away all the interaction with Google. I need to know what the HTTP requests should actually should look like.

One of the parameters in the authorization request is `access_type`. The description says

> Set the value to **offline** if your application needs to refresh access tokens when the user is not present at the browser.

I won't need to do that (I'll only want to retrieve a file on my server immediately after the user selects it) so in the spirit of not asking for more privileges than you really need, I used `access_type=online`. This gives me an access token and no refresh token. I've successfully used the access token to make some requests to Google Drive.

The user comes back the next day and tries to upload another file. While processing this request from the user, I make a request to Google Drive. The access token is expired, so I get a 401. What's supposed to happen next?

My guess is I should pretend this is a completely new user and send them through the full authorization process again. That would mean I have to abort whatever the user was trying to do, redirect them to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth` with all the parameters (`scope`, `client_id`, etc.) and embed enough information in the `state` parameter that I can resume the original request when the user gets back from their detour.

This seems rather difficult (in particular the part about saving and resuming the state of my application at some arbitrary point). It's a big enough obstacle that it should be explained somewhere. But the description of the `access_type` parameter didn't say anything about needing to insert authorization redirects everywhere. It just said the user must be "present".

Comment: About "I'll only want to retrieve a file on my server immediately after the user selects it", "my server" is your Google Drive? You want to make users use files downloading from your Google Drive at the web application. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike how can "my server" be Google Drive? Google Drive is on Google's servers. I'm not Google. I don't understand what arrangement you're describing, but it's not the one covered by the developers guide I linked to.

Comment: I'm really sorry for my poor skill. I had asked about the place of files you want to use. I had thought that the files are in Google Drive of your account. If this is my misunderstanding, can I ask you about "my server"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the right implementation. You don't need offline access if you aren't going to make requests when the user is not using the application. The thing is that access tokens expire in 1 hour. So you need to generate new access tokens if a user leaves the application and come back later.

If users have authorized your application, calling this URL with your configuration should return a new valid access token:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
 scope=scopes&
 include_granted_scopes=true&
 state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&
 redirect_uri=http://oauth2.example.com/callback&
 response_type=token&
 client_id=client_id
```

Comment: That looks very similar to the URL I would redirect the user to, if I wanted to redo the initial authorization. (The only part that looks different is `response_type=token` vs. `response_type=code`.) So this has to be a redirect, causing the operation in progress to be aborted?

Comment: `response_type=code` is necessary when requesting offline access. I forgot to tell you that you need to check [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#redirecting) instead. There, using Oauth2 endpoints, you will see that you need to generate that url and redirect the user to it in order to get an access token. I've always used JS library, so I'm not 100% sure, but I'm afraid you need to redirect the user to that url using oauth2 endpoints.

Comment: It's starting to make more sense to me now, as I've realized that the thing I'm trying to avoid (a user-visible redirect) is what provides Google with proof that the user is present. I don't think the "Client-side Web Applications" guide applies to me though.

Comment: I understand your scenario, with JS library it works pretty well... Anyways, did you try to generate a new access token making the request to that url? Just to confirm that I was right in case I need to use this solution in the future.

Comment: I can confirm that a redirect to the `/o/oauth2/v2/auth` URL does give a new access token, without actually showing the user an approval form. But it has to be sent to the user anyway, which means I do have to abort the operation in progress and restart it after the redirect. To avoid an explosion of complexity, I'm going to use refresh tokens instead.